# css pre wrap text not working

Tags: css, joomla, word-wrap, pre

Iam struggeling with text wrapping of my pre element. With the following css code, my text wrapping does not work, neither with FF nor with IE. The pre element is inside a div element called 'description'.

my css is:

```
#description {
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 550px;
}

#description pre {
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    word-break: break-all;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

CSS formatings border, font-family, font-size, etc. is working, the text wrapping not. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Just to confirm you do understand how `pre-wrap` works yes? As it's different to `pre` and `pre-line`. Have a look at the following for the descriptions just in case you don't >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: This is a very good source for getting the infos behind. After reading I dealed with all different settings to see the consequences. But none of the relevant settings solves my problem. The origin data are from a database table where the informations are stored sometimes with line-breaks. Before, I tried to display the data in normal divs. But this results, that the line-breaks were ignored. Now I try it with the pre-tag. The line breaks are fine, but while line-breaking sometimes the words are cutted. So I need to display whole words while line-breaking.

Comment: displaying whole words with line breaking is default. Could you please provide a screenshot of what is currently happening? And when your get the database from the database, are the line breaks already there using `<br>`?

Comment: No, in the database entries their are no <br> tags. There are line-breaks, like human readable line-breaks. Html tags are not allowed, these are normal textfields. If you still want screenshot, please let me know how can I provide you a screenshot?

Comment: take a screenshot of the output/display (what is displayed on the screen), upload it and provide a URL in your question or comment below ;)

Comment: http://s3.postimg.org/3oenwqaoj/pre.png - it is a german text. You can see at the end of the first line and the second line, that the words are broken. First line 'd-en', second line 'e-in', but it should be 'den' and 'ein'.